# htaccess: different rewrite rules for different ip addresses

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to apply different rewrite rules for different IP addresses using only one .htaccess file?

I have these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /version/1.0/index.php?r=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /version/2.0/index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

Both of the last two rules work fine, and I can choose which one to enable. 
I want to somehow enable one rule for myself in order to work on development version, and other rule for production.

Can I use somehow IP address filtering for that? Is that even possible? Is there any other alternative solution so I can have both two rules enabled, one for my development and other one for production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /version/1.0/index.php?r=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.456\.789\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /version/2.0/index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

You need to duplicate the rewrite conditions. Each set of  `RewriteCond`'s only apply to the *immediately following `RewriteRule`*. So the first rule will get applied to everyone who isn't hitting the webserver from the IP address: 123.456.789.123

Comment: Just perfect. What else to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.123
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /version/1.0/index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.456\.789\.123
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /version/2.0/index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This won't work because the second rule will now fire for existing files and directories as well. Look at @JonLin's solution.